# How to get a user using his user_id and assign channel-exclusive perms to him

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get a user using his ID or Username, and assign channel exclusive perms for him.
This is what i've tried:

```
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Tech Support Lead")
    user = self.bot.get_user_info(tickets[ticket]["ticket_data"][0][u'issuer_id'])


    ticket_perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    everyone_perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)

    techlead = discord.ChannelPermissions(target=role, overwrite=ticket_perms)
    everyone = discord.ChannelPermissions(target=server.default_role, overwrite=everyone_perms)
    ticket = discord.ChannelPermissions(target=user, overwrite=ticket_perms)

    await self.bot.create_channel(server, "Ticket Nr. {}".format(ticket), everyone, claimer, techlead)
```

When i run this code, i get an error `HTTPException - Bad Request`.

Comment: Possible typo? `get_user_info(tickets[ticket]["ticket_data"][0][u'issuer_id'])`. Should be `[u'isuser_id']`

Comment: `get_user_info` is a coroutine, so it needs to be `await`ed

Comment: nope, issuer_id refers to the ticket issuer(this is a ticket system)

Comment: Alright, i just found the problem. Im retarded and had a conflicting variable in the code. Also @PatrickHaugh thanks, that was also a problem.